# Multipolygon From Multilinestring PostGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon, linestring

I have been looking for a answer for days. I don't even know if its possible.

Tried:

```
ST_AsGeoJson(ST_MakePolygon(ST_transform(geom,4326)))
```

ERROR:  Shell is not a line

```
ST_Polygonize(ST_LineMerge(ST_transform(geom,4326)))
```

This returns one big polygon with all the multilinestrings, but I want separated polygons.

Is it possible? if yes, how can I do this?

```
TABLE rede.redetotal_geo
(
  circuit_id character varying(9),
  n_arvores bigint,
  km double precision,
  index double precision,
  geom geometry(MultiLineString,3857)
)
```

(Multilinestring -> Polygon)

[image]

These are my multilinestrings, I want to transform each color to a polygon.

Comment: You haven't described your inputs and outputs and what you get versus what you want particularly well. A picture (or two or three) is worth a thousand words.

Comment: Sorry, now I added the image

Comment: You can use `ST_ConcaveHull` to get approximate polygon. Since the lines don't actually form the boundary of the areas you're going to have some difficulty getting a perfect coverage of polygons from the data. Another possibility is building a line voronoi using the faces and assign faces to categories based on what lines fall within the faces. I don't know that PostGIS hast he functions for that (look at `ST_DelaunayTriangles()`)

Comment: Worked, thanks. is there a way to set your comment as correct answer?

Comment: But your's linestrings doesn't form a closed rings or anything else that seems to be a polygon.

Comment: Really do not form, but using concaveHull the result is very similar to that seen in the picture above, and the improvement in runtime speed is immense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ST_ConcaveHull to get approximate polygon. Since the lines don't actually form the boundary of the areas you're going to have some difficulty getting a perfect coverage of polygons from the data. Another possibility is building a line voronoi using the faces and assign faces to categories based on what lines fall within the faces. I don't know that PostGIS hast he functions for that (look at ST_DelaunayTriangles())